# Eclipse Web Project Request URL

Tags: java, eclipse, url, servlets, web-applications

I am trying to create a new dynamic web project in eclipse. I add a servlet and some basic html code to get it up and running. However I have one problem. When I make a get request via jquery using the url "/news" I get a 404 not found error.

```
$.get( // resulting url http://localhost:8080/news
  "/news",
  function(data) {
    alert('page content: ' + data);
  }
, "html");
```

When I check the full request URL I see `http://localhost:8080/news`. Makes sense because the project name should be in the url as well. So when I pass "project-name/news" into the get request I still get a 404 not found error.

```
$.get( // resulting url http://localhost:8080/project-name/project-name/news
  "project-name/news",
  function(data) {
    alert('page content: ' + data);
  }
, "html");
```

And this time the full request url shows `http://localhost:8080/project-name/project-name/news`... When I manually make a request to `http://localhost:8080/project-name/news` it works just fine. So why is eclipse adding the project name to the url?

Servlet declarations

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>NewsServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.crosbygames.servlet.NewsServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>NewsServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/news</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start with "/news" in the request URL, it will start as `http://localhost:8080/news`.

But if you use "news" (no slash "/"), it will start as `http://localhost:8080/<content path>/news`.

In your case, you are using `project-name/news` in your request URL, then resulting URL will be `http://localhost:8080/project-name/project-name/news` where `project-name` is your context path in your example.